# Redeclaration error fruit f vs fruit(f)

Tags: c++

```
class fruit{
  public:
       fruit(){  }
       fruit(int a){ cout << "int"; }
       fruit(const fruit& f){ cout << "fruit"; }
};
class apple{
    public: apple(){ }
            apple(fruit f){ }
};
int main(){
   fruit f;
   int a;
   fruit(f); // redclaration error ? why
   fruit(a); // invokes fruit(int) constructor
   fruit(fruit()); // invokes fruit(const fruit& f) function
   apple(f); // redeclaration error. why
}
```

I expected the `fruit(f)` to execute the `fruit(const fruit& f)` but it generates redeclaration error is this the parsing issue?

I just tried to pass `f` as argument to apple constructor but it generates redeclaration error.
Can one explain me why?

Comment: Is the `fruit(fruit())` line in your actual code also missing a `;`? Because you now have `fruit(fruit()) apple(f);` which probably explains the error you think you're getting.

Comment: [gcc disagrees with your comments](http://ideone.com/gJgD2t). Can you post which compiler you used?

Comment: @Angew I think this must be the compiler issue Thanks I have figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
fruit(f);
```

is exactly the same as

```
fruit f;
```

But you already declared something called `f` (another `fruit`.) You've declared `f` twice. That's why you get a re-declaration error. Along the same lines, this

```
apple(f);
```

is exactly the same as

```
apple f;
```

So, you're re-declaring `f` again. If you want to create an `apple` from `f`, you need

```
apple x(f);
```

Comment: Could you explain apple(f)? so is there no possibility to call apple constructor that accepts fruit object

Comment: @user3205479 What is there to explain? It is the same as `apple f;`. Exactly the same re-declaration problem.

Comment: @user3205479: See shuttle87's solution: `apple{f}` is unambiguously calling `apple::apple(fruit)`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you have

```
fruit f;
```

Which declares a variable `f` of type `fruit` then you have:

```
fruit(f);//same as: fruit f;
```

This isn't creating a new fruit with the parameter `f` but rather creating a variable `f` of type `fruit` which is likely not what you expect. which is making another variable which is assigned to `f`, which gives the error about the redeclaration.

```
apple(f);// same as: apple f;
```

Once again you are trying to re-declare the variable `f` here.

If you are wanting initialization and not a new variable, use the new uniform initialization syntax. This syntax was introduced with the express intent of removing this ambiguity, so use that instead:

```
fruit{f};
```

This ambiguity between initialization and declaration is sometimes referred to as c++'s ["most vexing parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). The new uniform initialization list syntax more closely matches your intent as it unambiguously says "this is an initialization and not a declaration".
See [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax) for more information on when to use this syntax.

Also in your example you are missing the semicolon after your classes, you want to fix that.

Comment: but why does it not think the same when I use fruit(a)?

Comment: @juanchopanza, I think my explanation was poorly worded, I made an edit to hopefully clarify.

Comment: @user3205479 `fruit(a)` is the same as `fruit a`. Seeing as you hadn't already declared a variable named `a` you won't get a re-declaration error.

Answer (score 3):

```
fruit(f); // redclaration error ? why
```

Because that's equivalent to the declaration `fruit f;` - you can put parentheses around the name in a declaration if you want to. There's already an `f` declared in this scope, so that's an error.

```
fruit(a); // invokes fruit(int) constructor
```

No it doesn't. Again, that's equivalent to `fruit a;`, and again fails since there's already an `a`.

```
fruit(fruit()) // invokes fruit(const fruit& f) function
```

No it doesn't. With the missing `;`, that's equivalent to `fruit fruit();` and declares a function (in the surrounding namespace).

```
apple(f); // redeclaration error. why
```

For exactly the same reason as the first two declarations.

Comment: It invokes the constructor I have compiled and checked your answers are misleading

Comment: @user3205479: I've also compiled and checked. They all behave as I described, as the language specifies they should.

Comment: Could you provide me the link where it is described and specified. Thanks

Comment: @user3205479: This is formally specified in the ISO standard. That's not free, but unofficial draft versions are free.

Comment: @user3205479: No, because the C++ standard isn't online (although you can see a draft [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)). Declarations are specified in chapter 7.

Comment: @user3205479: To demonstrate that no constructor is called in the only case that compiles: http://ideone.com/kDhg5h